# Perl data structure traversal -- reference followed key

Tags: perl, data-structures, traversal

Result: Many lines of `HASH(0x1948958) ARRAY(0x1978250)        ./directory/filename`

Desired result: `[Key of first hash]    [Key of second hash]    ./directory/filename #(elements of array, currently working)`

Catch: Should carry across to N level structures, hence my attempt at using Data::Walk.

What I really want to do as I walk the structure is to reference the key that is being used. Kind of like Data::Dumper but tab-separated instead of in code format. I think the likely solutions (in order of preference) are:

- Some call to Data::Walk that I've overlooked.
- A better module for this task that I don't know about.
- A quick code snippet that I can inline
- My own module / fork of Data::Walk / Data::Dumper (big frown) that will add this functionality.

---

```
use strict;
use File::Basename;
use Data::Walk;

my $files;
while (<>) {
        chomp;
        #ls -l output in a file; referencing filename from it (8th column)
        my @line = split(/ /, $_, 8);
        #fileparse exported by File::Basename
        my ($name,$path) = fileparse($line[7]);
        open (my $fh, '<', $path . $name);
        my $sha = Digest::SHA->new('sha1');
        $sha->addfile($fh);
        #finding files by basename, then unique hash, then however many places it is stored.
        #question not why I don't use the hash as the first field.

        #basename    digest    path
        push(@{$files->{$name}->{$sha->hexdigest}}, $path . $name);
}

my @val;
sub walkit {
        $val[$Data::Walk::depth - 1] =  $_;
        if ($Data::Walk::depth == 3) {
                print join("\t", @val), "\n";
        }
}

&walk (\&walkit, %$files);
```

Gurus?

Comment: What output do you want? Looks like you want three columns of output, but what do you wnt in the first two?

Comment: The keys I'm inserting -- basename, hash, full path. What I'm seeing instead of the keys are the structures redernced by the basename and hash keys.

Comment: Hello, I noticed you were involved in the "Healthcare IT" Stack exchange and thought you might be interested in this proposal -> [Healthcare Industry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41370/healthcare-industry?referrer=kaxVuDLRWM_Z_15aCbzplg2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: against my better judgement, I'll try to answer this question again.

Here's a simple approach to print what you want. Using Data::Walk is not feasible because you don't have key context when you are inside a hash (you just get a pointer to the container.)

This function works for somewhat complicated structures. Of course it will not give proper output if you put a function reference or something wonky in there.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $res;
sub walk {
    my ($item, $path) = @_;
    if (ref $item eq 'ARRAY') {
        foreach (@$item) {
            walk($_, $path);
        }
    } elsif (ref $item eq 'HASH') {
        foreach (keys %$item) {
            push @$path, $_;
            walk($item->{$_}, $path);
            pop @$path;
        }
    } else {
        print join('-', @$path, $item), "\n";
    }
}

my $struct = {
    a => {
            a1 => { a11 => [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
            a2 => { a22 => [5, 6, 7] }
    },
    b => { b1 => [ 99 ], },
    c => [ 100, 101, ],
    d => [ 101, { d2 => { d3 => [200, 210] }, }, ],
};

walk $struct;
```

Comment: The sample code won't magically change, but I would find it useful in other circumstances. Writing out multiple for loops for 2 deep isn't a big deal, but I'm thinking of larger structures, and I write these loops regularly. Sample code is meant as a sample, not "solve this directory listing problem." Also, the "File::Find" would have been unwieldy -- a lot of parsing work already occurred on that list.

Comment: So, you ask a question poorly and then downvote those who try to help. Great.

Comment: What did you add? It's harder to read than an answer that was there for an hour. It presumptively changes my input source. It contradicts where I already clarified, "I want an N-level compatible piece of code" by telling me I don't need it. I think this is a clear case of where an answer does not contribute to the question. Admitting and clarifying (before you answered) a poorly asked question does not what you provided helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
for my $name (keys(%$files)) {
   for my $digest (keys(%{$files->{$name}})) {
      my @qfns = @{ $files->{$name}{$digest} };
      if (@qfns > 1) {
         say "For $name and $digest,";
         say "   $_" for @qfns;
      }
   }
}
```

(I'm assuming you're looking for duplicates, so I print nothing when there's only one path associated with a name-digest combo. You can remove the `if` if you want to print everything.)

Some other cleanup:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Digest::SHA    qw( );
use File::Basename qw( basename );

sub calc_digest {
   my ($qfn) = @_;
   open(my $fh, '<', $qfn) or die $!;
   my $sha = Digest::SHA->new('sha1');
   $sha->addfile($fh);
   return $sha->hexdigest();
}

my $files;
while (<>) {
   my $qfn = (split)[7];
   my $name = basename($path);
   my $digest = calc_digest($qfn);
   push @{ $files->{$name}{$digest} }, $qfn;
}
```

("qfn" stands for "qualified file name", which means the path to the file, which wasn't what `$path` contained. You were repeatedly building the path even though `$line[7]` contained it.)

Comment: +1 for the clean code, but not an accepted answer because for an N level structure, I'm going to have to write all those for loops out (and that's what I started with).

Comment: @Jeff Ferland, You didn't ask about a N-level structure. It probably doesn't change the answer, though. Unless you want something general (like Data::Dumper), you will need nested loops. You just didn't figure how to do it cleanly. Hint: Use subs!

Comment: Fair enough to say I wasn't explicit about that, but I did attempt to imply it with my likely solutions comment. I'll explicitly change my question now.

Comment: I want to clarify -- +1 for a clean first loop. It was similar to mine, and worth something for the effort. "Didn't figure out how to do it cleanly" and "hint: use subs" (I did in the sample) feel extremely condescending, as does rewriting the entire code in a different style. Your edit to the comment makes me want to retract my vote (I haven't) and possibly kick you in the shins.

Comment: @Jeff Ferland, I thought you were going to change your question to something about an arbitrarily deep structure?

Comment: I understand looking at it initially and seeing a case of "solve this code", but the question does ask for an N-level. I'd be happy to have you edit my question to better ask it since I don't know how to better rephrase it without a re-write.

Comment: @Jeff Ferland, It's not a question of phrasing. You haven't asked any questions that deal with structures of arbitrary depths. What would this structure be? What do you want from it? What did you try to solve your problem?

Comment: A structure of arbitrary depth composed of hash and array elements in Perl. "I have X, I want to see Y, I want it to carry across to N-level structures" -- those are currently my first 3 lines. What I eventually did was view Data::Walk's source and modify it to track the key /index that brought it to the current level.

Comment: @Jeff Ferland, Sorry, but I have no idea what that means. I can't even tell if it's suppose to be an answer to one of my questions.