# In Perl, how can I create a hash table from two equal length arrays?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am trying to create a hash from 2 different arrays that are the same length. The elements of the 1st array will be the "keys," and the elements of the second array will be the values.

I tried the following code: FYI: the array "vss" refers to virtual server names, and "vsports" refers to tcp ports.

```
my %vsnhash;
@vsnhash {@vss} = @vsports;
print Dumper(\%vsnhash);
```

This works for me as long as all the elements (names) in the 1st array are unique. If they are not, I cannot access all the keys=>values in the hash because of a duplicated key.

How can I create an additional unique "level" or "key" to the hash that I could use to reference the data with duplicate names(or "keys") ?

Any suggestions or alternate solutions would be very helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < @vss; $i++) {
    push (@{$vsnhash->{$vss[$i]}}, $vsports[$i]);
}
```

Then access each hash key as an array. The array will be the size of the number of key references. There are some examples of that here: [Perl data structure traversal -- reference followed key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637042/perl-data-structure-traversal-reference-followed-key)

Comment: Just as a matter of style, I would have written `$i <= $#vss` rather than `$i < @vss`.  There's nothing wrong with the way you have it, but I find that I'm mildly uncomfortable with the way `@array` evaluates to the array size in scalar context; `$#vss` is more explicit.  (It's also robust in the presence of changes to `$[`, but nobody sane changes `$[`.)  Or I might have written `$i < scalar @vss`, which I'm sure some would find overly verbose.

Comment: I'd write it `for my $idx ( 0 .. $#vss ) {` It more explicitly expresses the idea that I want to loop over the indexes from 0 to the last index of `@vss`. The idiom is common enough that `perl` will optimize the range operator in this context to not build a list of values and instead iterate over the values one at a time, saving memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`each_array` from `List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aMoreUtils#each_array-ARRAY1-ARRAY2-...):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw( each_array );

my @k = qw(a a b c d d e e f);
my @v = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9);

my %h;
my $it = each_array(@k, @v);

while (my ($k, $v) = $it->()) {
    push @{ $h{ $k } }, $v;
}

use YAML;
print Dump \%h;
```

Output:

```
---
a:
  - 1
  - 2
b:
  - 3
c:
  - 4
d:
  - 5
  - 6
e:
  - 7
  - 8
f:
  - 9
```